# A new Angular7 project(nothing was changed) cnnot run，compiled successfully but cnnot open on 4200 port(chrome)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular-cli, frontend

I upgraded my angular-cli to ng7:

[image]

and I run 'ng new new_pro', then the project compiles successfully, like this:

[image]

run ng test，chrome still timeout：

[image]

But I recieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try running your app on some other port, like,

```
ng serve --port 8080
```

If the above command works then add that `port` (any port you like) in the `options` as default in the project's angular.json file, like -

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {
                        "port": 8080
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Only relevant properties are shown in this example.)